# Who is the blonde girl in the Deus Ex: Human Revolution opening credits?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

During the opening credits for Deus Ex: Human Revolution, after you've played through the epilogue and been caught by Barratt, and subsequently thrown through the glass wall you're presented with a nice cinematic where they're rebuilding Adam and a blonde girl appears in this video multiple times;

[image]
[image]

The image is blurry intentionally and appears this way during the cinematic, the full cinematic is below:

Who is she? Did I miss something else in the game as I do not remember this character being part of the story in game.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be [Megan Reed](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Megan_Reed), Adam Jensen's girlfriend.

[image: Megan Reed]

Comment: @Arperum, maybe the people who read this question and answer haven't played the game yet?

Comment: I hate spoiler markup and generally agree they're unnecessary, but at the same time, I don't think it's beneficial overall to remove spoiler tags in someone else's answer and then continue to argue for the removal when people want them put back in.

Comment: The [original revision](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/74321/1) has no spoiler text.  Just FYI for those arguing.

Comment: In that case, I support the edit to remove it again, for the exact same logic (in the other direction).

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza I'd argue anybody willingly clicking on something saying "who is this" no longer has the right to complain about spoilers.

Comment: @kalina, Arperum said as much, in a deleted comment.